# How to manually add all OSs to grub

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I currently have 3 OSs and 4 drives. I have Windows installed alone in an SSD, Ubuntu in a partition of an HDD that it shares with a partition for Windows files, and an Arch Linux installation on a different SSD. I tried to fix grub with helpers from Ubuntu and Arch Linux, and I tried to fix things with Windows installation disk. I think I have made things worse. I have not messed up the OSs themselves, but for all given purposes I have now 4 different bootloaders (2 grubs, 1 rEFInd and Windows boot) and none of them find all the OSs.

In other words I need to add the OSs one by one by hand, and understand what each entry in the grub configuration file means, so that if things break I can fix them. I don't want software to do it for me. I don't want Boot Repair. I want to do it myself, by hand, with the risk of breaking everything.

Comment: Since you seem to have UEFI, have you tried to use [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot) instead of grub? Install it and configure it on Arch.

Comment: I'd rather not try yet another bootloader, I have managed to setup grub with ubuntu and arch, I just need to get windows to work and all will be fine

Comment: Have you installed `os-prober`? Windows should be auto-detected. Manually, you should use `chainloader +1`, that's the final grub command to boot Windows. Still, systemd-boot is a lot easier to setup than grub and it automatically adds a Windows entry, although you'd have to manually manage the ubuntu entry (i.e after kernel updates).

Comment: Yes I have, os-prober doesn't find windows, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but left without answer. Here is my solution: what you will need, is one working os, and grub that once contained the os you want to bring back to life. I went into broken grub, by mounting broken partition to /mnt, and i went into 'grub.cfg' from '/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg' using VIM. There, I scrolled down to 'menuentry' that contained my 'Debian' which was unaccessible system. Copied whole 'menuentry' up to first in-line '}' and pasted it into my working 'grub.cfg' right below 'menuentry "Arch"{}'. This method worked for me, but i will also list things, which didn't work for me:

- Deleting grub and making Debian bootable
- Changing boot priority
- Updating grub
- Reinstalling grub
- Manually adding Debian, since I couldn't easily get all important parameters.

I hope this helps someone in future, sorry for bad grammar, I've been typing this on a phone, and this is not my first language.

Comment: I cannot remember hpow I fixed this since it was such a long time ago. I wiill mark it as the accepted answer.